# how to parse" http GET request"'s text response in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, parsing, facebook-graph-api, npm-request

I make a  HTTP GET request to Facebook to have  a long live token , as a response I have a plain text with the access token and expiration date , but I don't know how to parse it.

```
request.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' + APP_ID + '&client_secret=' + APP_SECRET + '&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=' + CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    .on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("body= " + data); 
    });

res.render('SocialMedia.ejs');
```

I tried data.access_token but it's undefined

Comment: can you post the output of your `console.log` statement?

Comment: access_token=(the token)&expires=5166486

Comment: Can you try with following url - `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token`? Notice that I've just included the version `2.8`. Now please check the response.

Comment: `body= {"error":{"message":"Missing redirect_uri parameter.","type":"OAuthException","code":191,"fbtrace_id":"F6gESsfgJr\/"}}` I going to search how to solve this uri problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow) documentation to get working with the lates `2.8` API (recommended). This will return a JSON response.

If you want to continue using your API then to parse your response which is in the form of url query params -

```
access_token=(the token)&expires=5166486 // data
```

You can do this -

```
var qs = require('qs');
var response = qs.parse(data); // assuming data is as mentioned above
console.log(response); // will print {access_token: (the token), expires: 5166486}
```

Now you can access the token like this -

```
response.access_token;
```

Comment: Thank you but I still have "undefined" in console. `request.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' + APP_ID + '&client_secret=' + APP_SECRET + '&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=' + CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .on('data', function(data) {
          var response = qs.parse(data);
            console.log("body= " + response.access_token); 
        });

    res.render('SocialMedia.ejs');`

Comment: Yay ! It's working , it's just needed to write this `Data = data.toString();` to don't have the "undefined" response , thank you very much !